# Why am I receiving an attribute error for my BeautifulSoup code when the variable in question has a value?

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

I am using Python 3.9.1 with selenium and BeatifulSoup in order to create my first webscraper for Tesco's website (a mini project to teach myself). However, when I run the code, as shown below, I receive an attribute error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Ozzie\Dropbox\My PC (DESKTOP-HFVRPAV)\Desktop\Tesco\Tesco.py", line 37, in <module>
    clean_product_data = process_products(html)
  File "c:\Users\Ozzie\Dropbox\My PC (DESKTOP-HFVRPAV)\Desktop\Tesco\Tesco.py", line 23, in process_products
    weight = product_price_weight.find("span",{"class":"weight"}).text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I am unsure what is going wrong - the title and URL sections work fine, but the weight and price sections return this value. When I have tried printing the product_price and product_price_weight variables, they have returned the values I expected them to (I won't post that here, it's just very long HTML).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

def process_products(html):
    clean_product_list = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    products = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"product-tile-wrapper"})

    for product in products:
        data_dict = {}
        product_details = product.find("div",{"class":"product-details--content"})
        product_price = product.find("div",{"class":"price-control-wrapper"})
        product_price_weight = product.find("div",{"class":"price-per-quantity-weight"})

        data_dict['title'] = product_details.find('a').text.strip()
        data_dict['product_url'] = ('tesco.com') + (product_details.find('a')['href'])
        weight = product_price_weight.find("span",{"class":"weight"}).text.strip()
        data_dict['price'] = product_price.find("span",{"class":"value"}).text.strip()
        data_dict['price'+weight] = product_price_weight.find("span",{"class":"value"}).text.strip()
        clean_product_list.append(data_dict)
    return clean_product_list 


master_list = []

for i in range (1,3):
    print (i)
    driver.get(f"https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/shop/fresh-food/all?page={i}&count=48")
    html = driver.page_source
    driver.maximize_window()
    clean_product_data = process_products(html)
    master_list.extend(clean_product_data)

print (master_list)
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Many thanks,

Comment: You execute ‘product.find()’ in a loop so it stands to reason that it could return ‘None’. You should check for this before using any variables assigned from the result.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How exactly do you recommend I do this?

Comment: Hello Ozgur, yep! somehow this variable of yourd `process_products weight` its value is `None` and you're doing a `.find()` to it. So yeah it will indeed cause an error.

Comment: How do you normally check for ‘None’?

Comment: Right, I understand that would make the most sense. But when I print the value of process_products_weight it returns the HTML that I am expecting, so the find should make sense.

Comment: Please read [mre].  Your question should included a minimal example of `html` , formatted as code, enough to reproduce the problem. When you [catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite is it still what you expected?  After catching the error please add the *value* of `product`, the complete tag including children, to your question, formatted as code.

Comment: This usually happens when the `find()` function does not find anything base on the element you provide, so it would return `None`. I think you need to check if this would be an issue that it returns `None` or else you could just add up a condition that if it's `None` then don't do a `.find()`

Comment: You should at least include one product tag - `"div",{"class":"product-tile-wrapper"}` - formatted as code, in your question. There may be a better way to extract the information  from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this by updating your `process_products` function. Take note again **THERE ARE CASES** where some of your variable that you are trying to do a `.find()` returns a `None` which simply means that it **HAS NOT** `find` any element base on the parameters given on your `.find()` function.

**Example this one:**

Let's say this part of code has been executed

```
product_details = product.find("div",{"class":"product-details--content"})
```

Now if it finds an element based on those `tags` & `class` it will return a `bs4` object but if not it will return `None` so let's say it returned `None`.

So your `product_details` variable will be a `None` object so once it is `None` again here on your code you do this. Again where `product_details` is `None`

```
data_dict['title'] = product_details.find('a').text.strip()
#Another way of saying is 
#data_dict['title'] = None.find('a').text.strip() ##Clearly an ERROR
```

So what I did this here is put it in a `try` `except` to simply catch those errors and give you empty strings indicating that probably your variable you're trying to do a `.find()` returns a `None` or might be some errors (the point is there is no relevant data being returned), that's why I use `try` `except` but you could also just make an `if` `else` out of this, but I think doing it in a `try` `except` is better.

```
def process_products(html):
    clean_product_list = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    products = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"product-tile-wrapper"})

    for product in products:
        data_dict = {}
        product_details = product.find("div",{"class":"product-details--content"})
        product_price = product.find("div",{"class":"price-control-wrapper"})
        product_price_weight = product.find("div",{"class":"price-per-quantity-weight"})

        try:
            data_dict['title'] = product_details.find('a').text.strip()
            data_dict['product_url'] = ('tesco.com') + (product_details.find('a')['href'])
        except BaseException as no_prod_details:
            '''
            This would mean that your product_details variable might be equal to None, so catching the error & setting
            yoour data with empty strings, indicating it can't do a .find()
            '''
            data_dict['title'] = ''
            data_dict['product_url'] = ''


        try:
            data_dict['price'] = product_price.find("span",{"class":"value"}).text.strip()

        except BaseException as no_prod_price:
            #Same here
            data_dict['price'] =''


        try:
            weight = product_price_weight.find("span",{"class":"weight"}).text.strip()
            data_dict['price'+weight] = product_price_weight.find("span",{"class":"value"}).text.strip()
        except BaseException as no_prod_price_weigth:
            #Same here again
            weight = ''
            data_dict['price'+weight] = ''



        clean_product_list.append(data_dict)




    return clean_product_list
```

Comment: Why not just catch the `AttributeError` and put a single try/except *around* the whole for loop suite - at least all the *.finds* - and then log,print, or pass in the except suite?

Comment: First of all with the `AttributeError` yes but I'm not assuming the type of error, I'll let the questioner decide for him to what he will put, of course putting the specific error is nice. Second put a single `try/except` around the whole for loop? I don't think so cause there might be cases that some of the variable might be `None` and some are NOT which actually finds a result text... so if that's the case it might affect other results which has no problem at all.

Comment: Thank you so much. The program is finally working. What I don't understand, however, is why now that I have added this try and except code in, the program works flawlessly, yet in the list that is created at the end, there are no missing sections. If there was an error previously, and a try except has been added, surely one would expect some of the data to be missing, since there was a none being returned in the first place? I am an amateur at this, just trying to understand the reasoning and logic behind this, as it is the correct solution afaik.

Comment: @wwii The idea here is if there's an element that returns `None` then just assign an empty string indicating that it has not found any element to get the text.

Comment: The reason you're getting a return value of  `None` on your respective values is simply because it `cannot` find those elements based on your given parameters. I also suggest to check `THE WAY` you find those elements :)... Also as you can see there... under the `except` I have put there to assign empty strings & the reason for it is simply because when it returns `None` still assign a value but an empty string indicating that no data has been found in that particular `find()` you are doing.

Comment: Right. I think I finally understand what I have done wrong. Thank you for all your help, and the time you took to answer my query. You have just made my day :)

Comment: Always welcome :) The idea is when it is `None` it simply means that the `.find()` function cannot or `did not` find the elements then simply assign an empty string... but incase you are wondering that when you check the `html` code & wonder why it cannot find the element when you put the parameters on the `.find()` function correctly ... I think that's another issue that you have to check with `THE WAY` you find the element :)